# Private VLAN setup / routing (L3 Brocade FCX)

Tags: networking, brocade

I'm new to networking and am working on setting up a simple flat private VLAN setup with a single Brocade FCX switch, a few hosts and connectivity from the facility.

Unfortunately due to my lack of some basic understanding I'm failing to grasp a small issue. Here is the current setup:

VLAN 100 (Primary VLAN)
- Has a VE assigned 192.168.5.1/24
- pvlan mapping for 101, 102 to 1/1/10

VLAN 101 (Community VLAN)
- Has two hosts

VLAN 102 (Isolated VLAN)
- Has one host

Now the PVLAN itself functions properly. If I hook up a server/PC to 1/1/10 I can see all of the broadcast traffic from the PVLAN fine. I'm however somewhat clueless as to how to get this to route / "work" as intended.

Where would I map the Primary VLAN to? Would I point it to the access port (1/1/1)? Is there a way to get it to use the VE device I created?

In all of the examples I'm seeing it's showing the Primary VLAN hooked up to a firewall (which makes sense, just not in my environment) however I'm looking to literally send it upstream directly.

Here is an example config:

```
vlan 100 by port
untagged ethe 1/1/10 
 router-interface ve 1
 pvlan type primary
 pvlan mapping 101 ethe 1/1/10
 pvlan mapping 102 ethe 1/1/10
!
vlan 101 by port
 untagged ethe 1/1/9 eth 1/1/12                                        
 pvlan type community
!
vlan 102 by port
 untagged ethe 1/1/11 
 pvlan type isolated
```

Thank you for any feedback / direction :).

Answer (score 0):

In hindsight it was a silly question. You'd configure the Primary VLAN to go out to "the network" - router, firewall, etc. In my case I'd be sending it it to the facility router.